# How can I display function return value on alertbox in asp.net

Tags: javascript

When we want to display the output of the javascript function on Alert Box.
I am unable to do so please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
alert(what_ever_function_you_want("some", "paramters"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   alert(yourfunction());
</script>
```